# Does EOS have state variables as in Ethereum?

Tags: smart-contract

Ethereum and solidity define state variables which are held in the contract. What is the structure in EOS? Is there also a **state variable system** at the contract level? Is the virtual machine defined as in Ethereum as a deterministic environment in which API calls etc are not permitted and only events link to the outside world (I understand events are not implemented in EOS now).

Answer (score 1):

To preserve state between different `actions` or `transactions`, EOS offers the [multi-index DB API](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/db-api), which allows you to create an indexed, persistent `table` / `struct` to preserve state. See [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/multi-index-table-tutorial) for a guide, and [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference) for the API reference.

Excerpt:

> EOSIO provides a set of services and interfaces that enable contract
>   developers to persist state across action, and consequently
>   transaction, boundaries. Without persistence, state that is generated
>   during the processing of actions and transactions will be lost when
>   processing goes out of scope. The persistence components include:
>
> 1. Services to persist state in a database
> 2. Enhanced query capabilities to find and retrieve database content
> 3. C++ APIs to these services, intended for use by contract developers
> 4. C APIs for access to core services, of interest to library and system developers

Example from [docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/multi-index-table-tutorial):

```
struct limit_order {
  uint64_t     id;
  uint128_t    price;
  uint64_t     expiration;
  account_name owner;

  auto primary_key() const { return id; }
  uint64_t get_expiration() const { return expiration; }
  uint128_t get_price() const { return price; }

  EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( limit_order, ( id )( price )( expiration )( owner ) )
};
...
eosio::multi_index< N( orders ), limit_order, 
   indexed_by< N( byexp ),   const_mem_fun< limit_order, uint64_t, &limit_order::get_expiration> >,
   indexed_by< N( byprice ), const_mem_fun< limit_order, uint128_t, &limit_order::get_price> >
    > orders( N( limitorders ), N( limitorders ) );
...
```

And, yes, EOS doesn't currently allow external API calls from the blockchain, but [inter-blockchain communication](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#inter-blockchain-communication) (IBC) and oracles are the suggested solutions for this in the future, with IBC being actively worked on by BlockOne.